# Dictionary inside python class is being treated as a static object?

Tags: python, dictionary, constructor, static, init

I have a simple data store object which uses a dictionary. 
When I create two instances of this object it seems the store dictionary is being treated as a static variable and the second object overwrites the first. However, the value variable in the class is not static. Here is a simple code example:

```
class Obj():
    store = {}
    value = None

    def __init__(self, id, name, value=None):
        self.store["Id"] = id
        self.store["Name"] = name
        self.value = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.store[item]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self["Id"]}:{self["Name"]} {self.value}'

obj1 = Obj(5680, "Dimmer", 100)
obj2 = Obj(5681, "ON/OFF", True)

print(obj1)
print(obj2)
```

What I get is this:

```
> 5681:ON/OFF 100
> 5681:ON/OFF True
```

But if I change where I define my store dictionary to the `__init__` method, it works:

```
class Obj():
    value = None

    def __init__(self, id, name, value=None):
        self.store = {}
        self.store["Id"] = id
        self.store["Name"] = name
        self.value = value
```

And the output is this:

```
> 5680:Dimmer 100
> 5681:ON/OFF True
```

I don't understand why in my first example it is treating the store dictionary as 'static'.

OK - It seems my store attribute is a 'class attribute' - REF: https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide

However, my value attribute is being treated as a 'instance attribute' as it is assigned a non-mutable value (None/Integer etc)

Comment: Get rid of class variable declarations `store = {}` and `value = None`. You are declaring them in the constructor, that's good enough.

Answer (score 2):

In here, you have:

```
class Obj():
    value = None # class-level variable

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value # object-level variable
```

Therefore, you have:

- `Obj.value`, which is a class-level variable (common to all `Obj` instances)
- `obj.value`, which is an object-level variable of `obj`, where `obj` is an instance of type `Obj`

Answer (score 1):

Because in you first example the variable are class attribute so they are common to all the class not the instance.

This article explain it very well https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

In python any variables which are assigned a value in the class declaration are static 
whereas any variables which are assigned values inside class methods are instance variables.

See [here](https://radek.io/2011/07/21/static-variables-and-methods-in-python/) for additional detail.